# No consigo poner elementos a la escucha con Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3

Tengo un pequeño problema: He creado una página HTML5, que se conecta a una base **MySQL** y recibe un **array** asociativo de productos. Para generar automáticamente una lista de dichos productos he generado este código en mi página:

```
foreach($array_productos as &$elemento){
    echo "<table><tr><td class='zoomIt' id='producto'>";
    echo $elemento['producto'] . "</td></tr></table>";          
}
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, se genera bien. Luego le he agregado propiedades **CSS** a la clase **zoomIt** para que me reaccione cuando pongo el cursor encima, y también funciona bien.
El problema es cuando quiero poner esa lista a la escucha de **JavaScript**. He probado con este código y no me funciona, solo me reacciona el primer elemento de la lista:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("zoomIt");
for (var i=0; i< divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("funciona");
    });
}
```

Lo he probado con **.getElementsByClassName** y con **.getElementsById**. ¿A alguien se le ocurre alguna solución?

Comment: ¿Ya te aseguraste que tu archivo .js sea cargado al final del documento?

Comment: No me puedo creer que sea algo tan simple... pues si era eso, evidentemente. Muchas gracias, pero para solucionarlo he encasquetado la carga del archivo dentro del body, y eso queda feo, hay alguna forma distinta y mas "elegante" de hacerlo?

Comment: Para ejecutar una función JS después de cargar el body, puedes hacer esto: <body onload="myFunction()">
Teniendo el JS donde toca.. No deberías tener problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego y Rubén... así da gusto.